# Creating custom attribute on C# which depends on services

Tags: c#, interface, attributes, dependencies, customization

I've created a custom attribute in C#, which authorizes the access to certain APIs, and doesn't have any parameters (paramaterless). Yet, in order to check the authorization, this attribute depends on a couple of services, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to manage that (it might turn out to be something relatively simple, I'm a relative newbie at C#). My problem seems to be how to properly inject a service into this class.

My attribute code (simplified) is something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute (IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }  

    protected override Boolean IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // validation code returning bool (which requires service)
    }
}
```

My problem is that when calling this attribute with [CustomAuthorize] the compiler gives me an error saying: "No argument given corresponding to required formal parameter 'service' in CustomAuthorizeAttribute(IService)".
So if I understand this correctly the constructor is expecting the service argument; yet how can I do it not to have to send the service from the Attribute call, but let the Attribute class handle that? Meaning, is there another way to inject services? Or, a different/better strategy altogether?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you override the `OnAuthorization` method, that gives you a `AuthorizationFilterContext` object that I think you can use to get services. Off the top of my head, something like `context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMyService>()` perhaps?

Comment: Thats the AuthorizeAttribute from Asp.Net? If so tag this question with that and mention the used version. Current Versions of Asp.Net don't have an IsAuthorized to override.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to return to this question and leave here potential solutions to it. I found a couple of articles describing different ways of injecting services. Though some of these options might not be ideal, in certain circumstances they can work well, so leaving it here as a reference: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/dependency-injection

Besides the above, @DavidG pointed me in the right direction and in this case I ended up going with:

```
var service = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService\<NameOfYourService>();
```